# Incorporating Armadillo library in an iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, linear-algebra, armadillo

I am trying to incorporate Armadillo linear-algebra library in an iOS application. Upon building, I am getting the following error:

> ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for
>   MacOSX file '/usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.dylib' for architecture
>   x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

I understand that when I built Armadillo library (ver 6.5) it did not built for iOS. I have seen tips on creating a fat library but have been unable to modify Armadillo makefile to do so. FYI, I am newbie when it comes to Linux/iOS/xCode development environment.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you just add the source and header files to your project and see if it compiles? I've done that for another C++ library.

Comment: I have tried that as well. Another thing that I have also tried is to use the toolchain file using the following to create Armadillo with iOS to no avail. https://code.google.com/archive/p/ios-cmake/

Comment: @shaanii you can use Armadillo without building it. `#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER` before including the armadillo header. Then link with the accelerate framework or whatever provides LAPACK and BLAS functions on iOS